# How to perform RSA encryption without padding, in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, padding

For example if I have a 1024-bit key, and wish to encrypt precisely 128 bytes of data, then padding is not required.

This is a usual method of encrypting:

```
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(plaintext, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
```

But there appears to be no `RSAEncryptionPadding.None`. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you have a 1024-bit key then 128 bytes of data is too much to encrypt.

Comment: Why is it too much data to encrypt?

Comment: Even with raw/unpadded RSA, you can only recover data where the message `m` as a big number is less than the modulus `n` as a big number. So if the modulus has a true 1024-bit spread it can do all 1023-bit numbers safely, but not all 1024-bit.  (0xFFFFFFFF...FFFF will not round-trip successfully).  So raw 1024 can safely do 127 bytes, but not all 128 byte messages.